# Filtering a Python List of URLS based on highest parameters URL contains

Tags: python, list, python-requests

Let's assume we have the following list of URLs:

```
http://url.com/search?q=apple
http://url.com/login?username=admin
http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1
http://url.com/search
http://url.com/login
```

Here we have 3 URLS which points to `/search`

```
1st url has `q` parameter : `http://url.com/search?q=apple` 

2nd URL has `p & q` both parameters: `http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1`
```

I would like to filter my list such that it should return only one entry for each URL which has the highest number of parameters along with:

EX: for below 3 URLS:

```
http://url.com/search?q=apple
http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1
http://url.com/search
```

- OUTPUT: (highest number of parameters URL)

```
http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1
```

Example of Entries:

```
http://url.com/search?q=apple
http://url.com/login?username=admin
http://url.com/cart
http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1
http://url.com/search
http://url.com/login
```

- OUTPUT:

```
http://url.com/cart
http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1
http://url.com/login?username=admin
```

How do I achieve that considering I have a large Python list of URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing URLs you can use `urllib.parse` module ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#module-urllib.parse)) - functions `urlparse` and `parse_qs`:

```
lst = ['http://url.com/search?q=apple',
'http://url.com/login?username=admin',
'http://url.com/cart',
'http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1',
'http://url.com/search',
'http://url.com/login']

from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
from itertools import groupby

get_url = lambda s: [urlparse(s).scheme, urlparse(s).netloc, urlparse(s).path]

l = sorted(lst, key=lambda k: get_url(k) + [len(parse_qs(urlparse(k).query))], reverse=True )
out = [next(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=get_url)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
['http://url.com/search?q=apple&p=1',
 'http://url.com/login?username=admin',
 'http://url.com/cart']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
def filter(urls):
    filtered = {}
    for url in urls:
        pos = url.find('?')
        prefix = url[:url.find('?')] if pos >= 0 else url
        query = url[(url.find('?')):] if pos >= 0 else ''
        params = query.count('&') + 1 if query else 0
        if prefix not in filtered or filtered[prefix][0] < params:
            filtered[prefix] = params, url
    return (url for _, url in filtered.values())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFBboMwEEXX5RQjFgGrKBB1h0I5CEKVFYbGkjGObapGVc9ObRwgqIk3RuP3Z@Z/5NWce/E2joPiGgqogpfwbIzM09RW9qe@SzVSdTqXl4JKyTFM/hO8/2SiHDQqQTssaNMx8YjbdtrJ4vCcejonDOogaLCFlnGDKnaLkzwAe3wFG@vj59dXegUWACbcpT3mjuydW9e4ZaKJozIi65vCln375yrfMDWwdtK@F5ABco0OWpSXAdX1Jow3QpI/kEbROpMq2rmVphbW7SBMHO0iAq9wcErfepJli8p19MuK3jiTSwLW9/xdeaSushqOt0FrEPe5zaRdw2PJ4k6hGZQAZ2oK9SOZc53F@y/KB9Qx8UEGUjFrgTNt4vs/Rcg4/gE)